# Render wpf margin according to current zoom level

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, vsix

I have developed a Visual Studio extension which has a custom margin using 
`IWpfTextViewMargin`. I render some glyphs on this margin against line numbers.

Normal scenario:

Start visual studio with 100% zoom level.
At normal zoom level everything works properly means glyphs are rendered according to line height and position. Even zoom in and zoom out works properly.

[image]

Problematic scenario:

Start Visual Studio with increased zoom level.
In this case the position of glyphs are distorted.

[image]

Any idea to correct this behavior? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue after applying wpfTextView layout transform to margin while initializing.